# Nested collection in a template

Tags: json, templates, backbone.js, nested, underscore.js

I need to access a nested object in JSON data.

**This is my JSON** :

```
[
    {
        "title": "Kategory 1",
        "id": 1,
        "products": [{ "name" : "Product 1"},{"name" : "Product 2"},{"name" : "Product 3"}]
    },
    {
        "title": "Kategory 2",
        "id": 2,
        "products": [{ "name" : "Product 4"},{"name" : "Product 5"}]
    }

]
```

**Collection :**

```
var Categories = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'api/categories.json'
});
```

**View :**

```
var CategoriesView = Backbone.View.extend({ 
    initialize:function () {
    this.render();
},

render:function () {
    var that = this;        
    var categories = new Categories();        
    categories.fetch({
        success: function (categories) {            
        var template = _.template($('#categories-template').html(), {categories: categories.models});           
          that.$el.html(template);
        }
    })
}             
});
```

**Template :**

```
<script type="text/template" id="categories-template">        
    <% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>

        <li class="categorycls"><%= category.get('title') %></li>
        <li class="productscls"><%= category.get("products") %>  

    <% }); %>                     
</script>
```

So my HTML now looks like :

```
Kategory 1

[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]

Kategory 2

[object Object],[object Object]
```

I am trying to render each product name like this :

```
Kategory 1

Product 1
Product 2
Product 3

Kategory 2

Product 4
Product 5
```

I saw some solutions for this [here](https://gist.github.com/geddski/1610397), but I'm novice in backbone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/template" id="categories-template">        
    <% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>

        <li class="categorycls"><%= category.get('title') %></li>
        <%  _.each(category.get("products"), function(product) { %>  
        <li class="productscls"><%= product.name %></li>
        <% }); %>
    <% }); %>                     
</script>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;

Comment: @MatejMarko, remove semicolon here: `<li class="productscls"><%= product.get('name') %></li>`

Comment: Thanks for help but still not function.... I have console error
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'each'

Comment: @MatejMarko, what version of Backbone u use? And I edit my answer again

Comment: Sergey Please How Can I update data from this json file ? I mean can I set timeout for view ? or collection ? I thinking about update every product name every 10 seconds...

Comment: @MatejMarko, yes, do it in `CategoriesView` : setInterval(function() { this.render(); }

Comment: Sergey I have few things for job... would you want extra income ? Only few things.... I think easy for you. Can I contact you with skype ?

Comment: With your solution console show me :

Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'render'

Comment: @MatejMarko. I think category.get("products") is BackboneCollection, but I look better and found it is `Array` - I edit my answer

Comment: Sergey your code is working thank you very much... You make me better day :)

Answer (score 1):

As is, your `products` attribute is an array which can be used to feed a nested template. For example,

```
<% _.each(categories, function(category) { %>

    <li class="categorycls"><%= category.get('title') %></li>
    <li class="productscls">
        <% _.each(category.get("products"), function(product) { %>
            <%= product.name %>
        <% }); %>
    </li>
<% }); %>
```

And a demo http://jsfiddle.net/nikoshr/htcbb/